# Consolidate Excel Formulas into Values

Tags: applescript, automator, ms-office

My client is having trouble with sheets containing formulae, so I am converting all the calculated values into hardcoded data. Apparently there is no native function to do this job. According to Microsoft's support, the *"solution"* (oh my God) is to select the cells you want, copy, select the first cell, execute "paste special", click values only:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/replace-a-formula-with-its-result-38001951-c0e8-4fbd-9048-37ef81e2891e

Now, this sounds like a poor mending, a patch, not a proper function. I would like to know if it is possible to achieve the same result with a quick AppleScrip action (even using UI) or maybe macros. I can deal better with Automator so I would rather not dive into VBA world, but I can change my mind if it is easier.

**What I need is:** select the cells, press a shortcut, replace the formula with its calculated result.

Comment: It seems quite reasonable when you have the choice to paste.special formulae or values or formatting etc as you wish - I’m happy with that flexibility...

Comment: From keyboard its ⌘ + C (to copy) and then ⌃ + ⌘ + V (to open paste special window) + V (to select Value) + ⏎. So it is 7 keystrokes. If you want replace only in one cell then F2 (go into cell editing mode) and then F9 (replace formula with value).

Comment: @SolarMike its not flexibility when you don't have a proper function to do the work. "Consolidate data" is flexibility.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg thanks for the input. It seems easy enough, but every extra step is a problem when you have several files per day, with formulas scattered through different areas of the sheet. I will try to write a script to do all the strokes in one pass.

Comment: When I install excel, one of the things I do the first day is add a handful of items to the toolbars, notably 'paste values' (and 'select current region'). You can also assign a keyboard shortcut to paste values which would reduce your keystroke count.

Comment: IMHO it's worth to better understand the "trouble with sheets containing formulae". What kind of trouble? What trouble is solved by replacing formulas with values?

Comment: @AivarPaalberg to be honest I don't know, there is a large chain of emails and I got a screenshot with #REF in the cells. So replacing the formulas with its values solved the problem. Basically the formulas are looking for data in secondary sheets within the same workbook. I guess it is something related to compatibility between software versions or language/region, I cannot be sure.

Comment: Based on my experience this is problem about how file is created and should be dealt at that stage. If references are not available anymore then it should be addressed while creating those references. Why they become unavailable? If formulas are not important then one can select whole sheet and paste values (without need to select specific cells), this will replace all formulas with values. As sheet anyway doesn't function as expected it should not be a problem.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg our client (Google Play) has their own formatting system, so the formula will go and look for data in our own metadata system (we can't change it because we don't work only for Google and furthermore they are not our main client - that will be Apple TV). There are no calculations involved but a lot of VLOOKUP formulas. I would love to know why they are getting #REF. There are only two sheets involved. If you have the time, please go and take a quick look, I am sharing it from my drive: https://bit.ly/3kzAi6l

Comment: This file contains external links to file /Volumes/RAID-QC01/SOFA DIGITAL/JOBS/QC/MATEUS/_RONALDO/Planilhas/FOURKIDSANDIT_SOFA_20201210_3381.xlsm (on sheet 'DATASOURCE', U7, V7 etc). In Excel menu: Data > Edit Links > Startup Prompt you can choose several options, one of them 'Don't display the alert and don't update automatic links', this should be enough to avoid automatic updates to files not available to reference and thus get rid of #REF.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg very good sir, thank you for your precious time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was way simpler than I thought. A simple GUI script solved the problem. However I still think Microsoft should implement a "consolidate all formulas" function. I wrote some feedback for them. Anyway, here is my simple, one shortcut solution:

```
on run {}
   tell application "Microsoft Excel" to activate
   tell application "System Events"
      key code 0 using command down --select all
      delay 0.5
      key code 8 using command down --copy
      delay 0.5
      key code 9 using {control down, command down} --paste special
      delay 0.5
      key code 9 --V (select values only)
      delay 0.5
      key code 36 --return
   end tell
end run
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler, faster method to replace formulae with values using the paste special command. It is set to work with the used range but the focus can be narrowed easily enough (see comments).

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    
    set ur to used range of active sheet -- copy from where
    -- to reduce affected area…
    -- set ur to intersect range1 ur range2 column "A:B"
    
    copy range ur -- to clipboard
    
    activate object range "A1" of active sheet -- paste where
    paste special range "A1" what paste values
    
end tell
```

I'm leaving my original answer here as it is valid and can be useful in other circumstances, such as if you wished to further process each cell.

This will grab the value of every cell of a sheet's used range, and then cycle through each cell of that range and replace its contents with its value. I've added an optional line to limit the affected range.

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
tell workbook 1
tell active sheet

```
        set ur to used range -- where      
        set ur to intersect range1 ur range2 column "A:B" -- limit where
        
        set cv to value of cells of ur -- what          
        repeat with x from 1 to count of cells of ur
            set value of cell x of ur to item x of cv
        end repeat
        
    end tell
end tell
```

end tell

Finally, here is a mouse-driven solution that I found on macexcel.com at [Change formulas to values](https://macexcel.com/examples/othertopics/formulasvalues/) under Manual way 2.

Select the range you wish to affect and hover the cursor over the right or bottom edge of the selected range. The cursor will change to a hand. Right-click and begin to drag the selection, then the cursor will change to a fist. Make sure you haven't actually moved the selection and release the button. An alternate contextual menu results. Click `Copy Here as Values Only` and the selection's values will be pasted over its current contents. And of course, you can create a keyboard shortcut for Paste Values which allows for a quick and easy solution.

Comment: Interesting. It is elegant and it does work! However it took a long time to process just a few lines. The copy paste approach is almost instant. This could be one of the few cases where using some UI shortcuts can be more effective.

Comment: Roughly speaking, how many rows/columns are in your used range? Also, in your question, you mention selecting cells… if you did that, approximately how many would there be?

Comment: thank you for all your trouble, I wrote a simple script that did the trick. I hope your solution will help other people. If you still wish to test your code I have a sample file here with all the formulas grabbing data from the second sheet: bit.ly/3kzAi6l